# Julia's most efficient way to choose longest array in array of arrays?

Tags: arrays, max, julia

I have an array of arrays `A` which is an `N-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}` of integers. I am trying to find the largest array in `A` using Julia.

For example:

```
A =  [[1, 2], [3, 4], [5, 6, 7], [1, 2, 5, 8]]
```

In Python I would simply do: `max(A, key=len)` but in Julia I don't know how to do it.

What I did is this:

```
L = []
for a in A
    push!(L, length(a))
end
A[findmax(L)[2]]
```

Thanks!

Comment: What was the output of the Julia code pasted above?

Comment: The output was: `4-element Array{Int64,1}:  1  2  5  8`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**UPDATE:** For v1+ you'll need to replace `indmax` in this answer with `argmax`.

**EDIT:** Note, it is also worth checking out the other answer by @crstnbr

Consider the following example code:

```
julia> A = [[1,2], [1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3]]
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2]            
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
 [1, 2, 3]         

julia> length(A)
3

julia> length.(A)
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 6
 3

julia> indmax(length.(A))
2

julia> A[indmax(length.(A))]
6-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
 4
 5
 6
```

The first call to `length` gets the length of the outer vector in `A`, which is *not* what we want. In the second call, I use the [broadcasting operator](https://docs.julialang.org/en/stable/manual/functions/#man-vectorized-1) `.` so that I instead get the length of each of the inner vectors. In the `indmax` line, I'm finding the index of largest value in `length.(A)`, ie the index of the longest inner vector. If you instead want to return the longest inner vector, you can just index into `A` using the result of the `indmax` line.

Comment: Solid concise answer

Comment: Thank you. If `A` was a dictionary, is it possible to do it? For example, `Dict(1=>[1,2],10=>[1,2,3,45])` and I would like to return the `key` of the largest array? Here, I would like to return `10`.

Comment: @Jarbou That's a bit less neat since broadcasting doesn't work with dictionaries. I think `collect(keys(x))[indmax([ length(v) for v in values(x) ])]` will do the job, although I'm no dictionary wizard, so someone else might know of something more efficient.

Comment: `length.(A)` will create copy of array which is probably not the best. Unfortunately I didn't find any normal solution (I am still beginner!). Best "oneliner" I could propose in this moment is -> `maxx(a, keyfun) = a[mapreduce((x) -> (x[1], keyfun(x[2])), (x,y) -> y[2]>x[2]?y:x, enumerate(a))[1]]; maxx(A, length)`  which is ugly and probably it could be better to write function with empty array checking, and with for cycle.

Comment: indmax is not defined in Julia 1.3

Comment: @OrangeSherbet Thanks for the reminder. I'll update answer to `argmax`

Answer (score 7):

@Colin has provided a compact, convenient answer. However, if speed matters (op asked for most efficient way) this should be close to optimum

```
function findlongest(A)
    idx = 0
    len = 0
    @inbounds for i in 1:length(A)
        l = length(A[i])
        l > len && (idx = i; len=l)
    end
    return A[idx]
end
```

Note that this implementation would (presumably) be a really bad idea in Python :)

**Quick benchmark:**

```
julia> using BenchmarkTools

julia> A = [[1,2], [1,2,3,4,5,6], [1,2,3]]
3-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2]            
 [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
 [1, 2, 3] 

julia> @btime findlongest(A);
  26.880 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime A[indmax(length.(A))];
  9.813 μs (25 allocations: 1.14 KiB)
```

That's a **~365 times speedup** for this example.

**EDIT:** **Better benchmark (suggested in the comments)**

```
julia> @btime findlongest($A);
  9.813 ns (0 allocations: 0 bytes)

julia> @btime $A[indmax(length.($A))];
  41.813 ns (1 allocation: 112 bytes)
```

The `$` signs avoid setup allocations and times. Speedup *~4*.

**Quick explanation**

- for loops are fast in Julia, so why not use them
- avoid allocation (`length.(A)` allocates a new array of integers)
- `a && b` is shortcut for "if a then b"
- `@inbounds` avoids bound checks for `A[i]`

Comment: Try `@btime $A[indmax(length.($A))];` to get better timings avoiding setup allocations.

Answer (score 1):

`indmax` is no longer defined in Julia (at least 1.3).

Use `argmax` instead.

```
>>> A = [[1,2], [1,2,3]]
2-element Array{Array{Int64,1},1}:
 [1, 2]   
 [1, 2, 3]

>>> length.(A)
2-element Array{Int64,1}:
 2
 3

>>> argmax(length.(A))
2

>>> A[argmax(length.(A))]
3-element Array{Int64,1}:
 1
 2
 3
```